# How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?

Tags: python, macos, pip, installation

I spent most of the day yesterday searching for a clear answer for installing `pip` (package manager for Python). I can't find a good solution.

How do I install it?

Answer (score 3470):

On Linux or MacOS:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

If you want to install `pip` for Python 3, replace `python` with `python3`.

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/ for more details.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, make sure http_proxy and https_proxy are set correctly, then use the '-E' option with sudo:  sudo -E easy_install pip

Comment: `Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg` -- what about my python3 installation? Does this just mean that pip uses my python2 installation?

Comment: If you're not running as admin (arguably you shouldn't) you'll need to do su admin_account_name and then provide admin account pw when prompted. After that you can run sudo easy_install pip.

Comment: An extra warning: don't run this when a homebrew based python installed and occurs earlier in PATH (e.g. when you change /etc/paths): it would install pip with root credentials for the wrong python

Comment: @acidjunk What do you do if you have a homebrew based python installed and occurring earlier in PATH?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist a home brew python already has pip. If you want to add pip to the Mac OS variant you could invoke the correct easy_install by using it's full path: sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip

Comment: Never sudo install a package for any language. This is insecure and will ruin your life later as more and more packages need sudo permissions.

Comment: This is only a partial solution. Some pip packages will try to overwrite files that are readonly in the macOS stock Python installation and therefore fail to install. This is a case where you are better off installing a separate version of Python and using it exclusively - whether via Homebrew, MacPorts, pyenv, virtualenv, or whatever.

Comment: @acidjunk is correct. In ML/DS you will have python2 and python3. MacOS default python2 is in `/usr/bin` so that's why you need to do `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip`. python3 should be installed in `/usr/local/bin`. This means python versions will never conflict with each other. So whenever you use `python` or `pip` this will only install python2 versions. Whenever you use `python3` or `pip3` this will only install python3 versions. As a bonus, when you install jupyter in python2/3 virtualenvs, jupyter will automatically use the correct kernel.

Comment: Worked without sudo for me.

Comment: You know what would be even easier? 

brew install pip.

Since brew is the most popular package manager for OSX and people will generally try to install through that. For example, when I needed pip just now I just went straight to brew and typed in the above command assuming that it would be there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip - there are some risks to installing using sudo

Comment: Got error #notsoeasy Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

Comment: @htafoya I got the same error. [This worked](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/) for me instead. `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && sudo python get-pip.py`

Comment: Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

Comment: I get "error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')"

Comment: Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?) -
No local packages or download links found for pip -
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

Comment: Same Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip') error

Comment: `sudo easy_install pip` work for me, `get-pip.py` don't

Comment: this answer needs to be updated. the correct answer is now get-pip.py. its quite likely that using the older method still works particularly if other versions of py (<3.7) exist in the environment.

Comment: Easiest way to install pip after easy_install got deprecated:


1. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

2. python get-pip.py

Comment: Here's a nice one-liner:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

Comment: where does the pip binary go after installing with get-pip.py? I don't see it in my PATH anywhere.

Comment: Or `curl -L get-pip.io | sudo -H python`.

Comment: Is there a Reason why this script consists of 1.7MB of compressed data? Smells fishy to say the least.

Comment: This LOCKED post is a great example of what's wrong with SO.

I post answers firstly for me, s.t., I can look back and see what I consider the "correct answer"; Others benefit as well.

Hopefully, SO offers a "Search for your own comments" feature s.t. I can find my answer in the future.  So, here goes...

Now-a-days, it's very simple:

1) brew install python
2) echo 'alias pip=pip3' >> ~/.bashrc

As per https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python brew installs pip as "pip3". So, we create a 'pip' alias, which will be active the next time we open a new terminal shell.

Comment: I’m shocked what a pain this is coming from Windows where you run a simple installer and pip just works!

Comment: @l3x - i discovered (1) there is a your-own-comments function. look on your profile. ask on meta if needs be.  **however** - (2) great tip: stackoverflow's search mechanisms are utterly laughable. Do this: 1 open a fresh browser window.  2 assuming you have ordinary google as your default search.  3 type in exactly (no quotes) "stackoverflow.com " (notice the space) and then type your nickname (say, "fattie") and then type the topic or search terms. Because Google is appox. 18 billion times better than SO, it will instantly find just what you have in mind. It's a life saver.

Comment: brew install pipx

Answer (score 774):

#### ⚡️ **TL;DR** — One-line solution.

Run the following command for Python v2.7 (default on Mac as of 2021)

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py | python
```

Run the following command for Python v3

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

*Or* the following if you have it installed as Python 3

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Another GIF image you said? Here you go!

[image: GIF install pip]

---

**The** ***following used to work*** **in 2019 and before**

All you had to do was:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

#### 2019: ⚠️`easy_install` [has been deprecated](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html). Check **Method #2** below for the preferred installation!

**Details:**

> ⚡️ OK, I read the solutions given above, but here's an **easy** solution to install `pip`.

The macOS comes with the Python environment installed. But to make sure that you have Python installed open the terminal and run the following command.

```
python --version
```

If this command returns a version number that means Python exists. This also means that you already have access to `easy_install` considering you are using macOS or OS X.

ℹ️ Now, all you have to do is run the following command.

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

After that, `pip` will be installed and you'll be able to use it for installing other packages.

P.S. I ended up blogging a post about it. [QuickTip: How Do I Install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://ahmadawais.com/install-pip-macos-os-x-python/)

---

#### ✅ Method #2: Two line solution

`easy_install` [has been deprecated](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html). Please use [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) instead.

Download and install PIP

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Try using`sudo`

Comment: After trying out python get-pip.py I get ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.1.1.dist-info/RECORD'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: I just tried, http://on.ahmda.ws/424d72 — it's working as expected. Are you using the second up to date method?

Comment: After `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`, I get this `curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to bootstrap.pypa.io:443` any ideas ? @AhmadAwais

Comment: Looks like an SSL error. Can you try running the same without `https` and with `http`?

Comment: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError`

Comment: Here's a nice one-liner: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

Comment: Don't use `sudo` for `python` on `macos`! 

First make sure you own it (`$ sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local`), then use `/usr/local` for all python programs, e.g. installing `pip`: `/usr/local/bin/python3 get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local --upgrade`

Comment: And don't let Homebrew mess up `/usr/local`: tell it to use `/opt/local` or elsewhere

Comment: what did you use for GIF?

Comment: ^For that check out https://AhmadAwais.com/uses page.

Comment: Could we consider updating this in the light of python2 being deprecated (but still present) on BigSur and python3 being an entirely different command?

Comment: The updated method I listed still works for me though?

Comment: And note: the "system" python on MacOs is STILL python2. If you want to install a module for THAT python, you need `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py | python`. (because the other one is for python3!)

Comment: 2021 update: I had to do `python3 get-pip.py` because I was getting the `This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6` error the original way. Otherwise this worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 553):

I'm surprised no-one has mentioned this - since 2013, python itself is capable of installing `pip`, no external commands (and no internet connection) required.

```
sudo -H python -m ensurepip
```

This will create a similar install to what `easy_install` would.

Comment: Perfect! My system could not locate easy-install, so the other solutions did not work.

Comment: This worked from behind a firewall where the others failed. Thanks!

Comment: sudo -H is better in this case

Comment: @MattSephton you're right, but I wouldn't be worrying about the cache for this command - when run on python 2.7 it downloads pip 6.1, which will definitely need to be updated.

Comment: I'm confused, `sudo -H` has nothing to do with the cache? it's a security policy directive.

Comment: @MattSephton the reason -H is necessary when using `pip` (as far as I understand) is to ensure the right user owns the cache directory.

Comment: This helps if you have multiple versions of python, and need a specific one to get pip.

Comment: @Teepeemm, how can I then target the proper pip installation to use pip for subsequent package installations?

Comment: @user3.1415927 you could use `/path/to/your/python -m pip <command>`

Comment: Best solution, worked like charm on MacOS. easy_install was giving download errors.

Comment: Not anymore...
`$ sudo python -m ensurepip
Password:
The directory '/Users/jdoe/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/jdoe/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`

Comment: how to undo this?

Answer (score 533):

You can install it through Homebrew on OS X.  Why would you install Python with Homebrew?

> The version of Python that ships with OS X is great for learning but
>   it’s not good for development. The version shipped with OS X may be
>   out of date from the official current Python release, which is
>   considered the stable production version. ([source](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/))

Homebrew is something of a package manager for OS X.  Find more details on the [Homebrew page](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).  Once Homebrew is installed, run the following to install the latest Python, Pip & Setuptools:

```
brew install python
```

Comment: Pip isn't running even after following your steps? I restarted the shell but still no avail.

Comment: Have you made sure that you've got ```/usr/local/bin``` in your PATH? Try running ```/usr/local/bin/pip``` which is a full path to the pip program.

Comment: The folder /usr/local/bin/pip was in path but pip wasn't running. I deleted the folder and reinstalled it and now it runs. Thanks !!

Comment: how you deal with two versions of python installed ? if you want to install a module via pip, this will install it only in the brew version, hence, if you run something like python script.py which requires that module, you will get an error...

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9 has python 2.7.5 by default

Comment: Note that if you use homebrew, then you end up using your own python, not the system one.   This is the road to hell if you want to use wxpython ...

Comment: @GreenAsJade What is the solution then?

Comment: @JorgeBucaran pretty sure you can ensure the right paths are in $PATH, and you will point to the correct version of python you intend to use. i.e. /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin. If you've already got a version of python on mac osx, then use the `easy_install` method mentioned

Comment: @JorgeBucaran ... sorry I only just saw your question!   As per the most accepted answer, easy_install pip with sudo.

Comment: I like this solution as "sudo" is not required. Let's not stuff around with the system's python.

Comment: Installing python with homebrew also installs pip. Everything is locally installed and doesn't require `sudo`.

Comment: Yes, this answer, plus I had to do `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: It is the best way to use `pip`. Installing package with `sudo` when `pip` is installed with `easy_install` cases problems.

Comment: If you brew-install Python, but `pip` is still not in your path, you might need to re-link, like this `brew unlink python && brew link python`

Comment: In my case, after installing python 2 and 3 I noticed that there was no default `python` symlink in /usr/local/bin (thus `python` still went to system python). A quick symlink in /usr/local/bin to the brewed python of choice did the trick, but keep that in mind if you hope to have a homebrew-installed python when you type `python`. Beyond that, `python2` / `pip2` (and/or `python3` / `pip3`) work accordingly for the latest brew-installed python versions.

Comment: brew update && brew reinstall python@2     has worked for me recently

Comment: Homebrew is a serious security problem. The default install opens /usr/local/ to any malicious program that happens onto your account. Basically you are back to the (non) security of windows 3.1.  /usr/local/bin is first in your path thus a malicious program can replace trusted system utilities without you noticing.

Comment: Still no `pip` symlink after `brew link python`, but do have `pip3`. Are we expected to make the symlink manually?

Comment: after brew install python ,pip3 will be installed. Set alias for pip to pip3 and you should update pip at once, by this command:pip install --upgrade pip --user

Comment: pip command not found after installing python 3 with brew

Answer (score 141):

On Mac:

1. Install easy_install

   ```
   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
   ```
2. Install pip

   ```
   sudo easy_install pip
   ```
3. Now, you could install external modules. For example

   ```
   pip install regex   # This is only an example for installing other modules
   ```

Comment: Above solutions all yielded DistributionNotFound exceptions. This worked perfectly.

Comment: I had to restart the terminal after easy_install install, and i had to run SUDO on pip install something.. But after that, works perfectly

Comment: The latest OSX is already bundled with easy_install and calling `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python` will break your setup! Don't install easy_setup if you already have it, I've spent an hour to repair my setup after this command (thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac).

Comment: Downvoting for piping curl directly into an interpreter... common as this practice is, it's something I don't like the security implications of. (Also, I think there are better answers for this question.)

Comment: These are also the official instructions from amazon too - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html

Comment: Get "ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile" in step 2. Please use "sudo -H python -m ensurepip" instead.

Answer (score 125):

### [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina)

[Install Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation):

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Add the path:

```
sudo nano  ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Install Python 3:

```
brew install python
```

This Python (v3) also installs pip3. In order to use only 'pip', add an alias:

```
sudo nano  ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this line:

```
alias pip=pip3
```

### [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave)

macOS comes with Python 2, but not with `pip`. Anyway, it's better to manage it with Homebrew. You must [install it before](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation).

Install Python 2:

```
brew install python
```

**WARNING**: for a modern macOS (2019) this can install Python 3, and for Python 2 you really need to do: `brew install python@2`

Install Python 3:

```
brew install python3
```

Python 3

If you install Python 3, pip will be installed automatically.

```
brew install python3
```

As of 2019, now to use pip version 3, use `pip3`. Or you can execute: `python3`, to use version 3. When you install packages with pip3 they will be separated from Python 2.

For older versions: You need only to upgrade pip, but before that you need create a virtual environment to work with Python 3. You can use a project folder or any folder:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Check the versions:

```
pip -V
python --version
```

After 2019:

```
pip3 -V
python3 --version
```

To deactivate the environment:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: For me, `sudo python get_pip.py` worked well, cause on OS X python is already installed!

Comment: This may be an option to go with if you want to use a newer version of Python since Macs default install of Python is 2.7.x. You would do this by changing step 2 above to python3 instead of python.  Additional note, the brew install of python will also install pip, and provide info on upgrading/uisng pip.

Comment: @DeliciaBrummitt i've corrected my answer in accordance to your suggestion, and I've added a new block for python3

Comment: `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3 get-pip.py` for Python3 on El Capitan.

Comment: My pip is called `pip3`

Comment: Now installing python2 is `brew install python@2` and `brew install python` installs python3

Comment: As suggested: if you already have `pip3`, simply alias it to `pip`, like so: `echo 'alias pip=pip3' >> ~/.zshrc` (if you're not using zsh, change `.zshrc` to your shell)

Answer (score 90):

`pip` is available on OS X via `easy_install`.

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

When prompted for a password, enter your normal login password.
After the installation has completed, you should be able to use `pip` as expected.

*Note: this works for other Python packages as well*

Comment: This one line fixed pip on my Mac when all I got before was some kind of _DistributionNotFound_ exception trying to install something via pip.

(Mac OS X 10.10.4, Python 2.7)

Comment: I had to also then run `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Is pip depended on python version? I installed python3, but this command seems to be using python2. pip is installed successfully, though.

Answer (score 86):

The simplest solution is to follow the [installation instruction from pip's home site](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip).

Basically, this consists of:

- downloading [get-pip.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py). Be sure to do this by following a trusted link since you will have to run the script as root.
- call `sudo python get-pip.py`

The main advantage of that solution is that it install pip for the Python version that has been used to run `get-pip.py`, which means that if you use the default OS X installation of Python to run `get-pip.py`, you will install pip for the Python install from the system.

Most solutions that use a package manager ([Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) or [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts)) on OS X create a redundant installation of Python in the environment of the package manager which can create inconsistencies in your system since, depending on what you are doing, you may call one installation of Python instead of another.

Comment: I have a second brew installed python, but I am trying to install pip on my original /usr/bin mac python. Do you know how I can access pip for that installation? I used /usr/bin/python to install pip, but pip wasn't in /usr/bin/.

Comment: @Wesley How did you get that second installation? If you are using a python version manager there should be an option to set the python version you want and then you should be able to install pip for that specific version via the method above.

Comment: It is unsecure, because you run ```get-pip.py``` under ```sudo```, but you can't guarantee that you downloaded proper ```get-pip.py``` until you know checksum. More on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587473/what-is-get-pip-py-checksum-where-can-i-get-it-for-sure

Comment: It looks like the linked page has moved to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ which mentions "Warning! Be cautious if you're using a Python install that's managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state."

Comment: That warning is confusing to me because using the `git-pip.py` script to install pip for Apple's stock python is the main use case for the script existing vs just installing python via homebrew.

Answer (score 48):

For those who have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, here's the solution:

```
python2.7 -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Additionally, if you want to install pip for Python 3.6:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```

Comment: this needs to be the accepted answer _for recent pythons_, so that people stop doing the old silly stuff

Comment: python get-pip.py

Comment: Thank you so much and this is working for me. I got a old mac and upgraded the system. I was try to install some pip packages with python 2 pip and this help me out. to whom not sure how to check, `pip -V` to check the pip version and `pip freeze` to check the installed package.

Answer (score 44):

Installing a separate copy of Python is a popular option, even though Python already comes with macOS. You take on the responsibility to make sure you're using the copy of Python you intend. But, the benefits are having the latest Python release and some protection from hosing your system if things go badly wrong.

To install Python using [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew update
brew install python # or brew install python3
```

Now confirm that we're working with our newly installed Python:

```
ls -lh `which python`
```

...should show a symbolic link to a path with "Cellar" in it like:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 chris  admin    35B Dec  2 13:40 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/bin/python
```

Pip should be installed along with Python. You might want to upgrade it by typing:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now you're ready to install any of the 50,000+ packages on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

#### Other Notes

Formerly, I've used [get-pip.py to install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html). But, the docs warn that get-pip.py does not coordinate with package managers and may leave your system in an inconsistent state. Anyway, there's no need, given that pip is now [included with Python as of 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2.7//installing/index.html).

Note that pip isn't the only package manager for Python. There's also easy_install. It's no good to mix the two, so don't do it.

Finally, if you have both Python 2 and 3 installed, *pip* will point to whichever Python you installed last. Get in the habit of explicitly using either *pip2* or *pip3*, so you're sure which Python is getting the new library.

Happy hacking!

Comment: actually, `python` symlinks to python2, and `python3` symlinks to python3... regardless of which was installed last.

Comment: This page from Homebrew docs explains which version each command points to: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

Answer (score 31):

You should install [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`) first:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then brew install Python

```
brew install python
```

Then `pip` will work.

Comment: But - you have not installed pip in the system python in this case, rather you have installed a new python and pip along with it.   Then you will be into all sorts of strife trying to use wxpython...

Comment: for me brew didn't set the symlinks for python and pip, 

ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: You can try running these two codes 

1. Open the Terminal app via Launchpad. | curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py | python3 get-pip.py

Answer (score 30):

Download this file: [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Then simply type

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Make sure you are in the same directory as *get-pip.py* or you supply the correct path for that file.

For details, you can visit: *[Installation - pip documentation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)*

Or, http://thegauraw-blog-blog.tumblr.com/post/47601704154/how-to-install-pip-in-both-windows-ubuntu-easiest-way

Comment: This worked for me thanks. Only one small change, I needed to use python3 so: sudo python3 get-pip.py

Comment: The second link is broken (*"Not Found. The URL you requested could not be found."*).

Answer (score 27):

On the recent version (from [Yosemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) or [El Capitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) I believe... at least from [Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) onward), you need to run `brew postinstall python3` after `brew install python3` if you use [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)).

So,

```
brew install python3 # this only installs python
brew postinstall python3 # this installs pip
```

---

### Homebrew version after 1.5

According to [the official Homebrew page](https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/):

> On 1st March 2018 the python formula will be upgraded to Python 3.x and a python@2 formula will be added for installing Python 2.7 (although this will be keg-only so neither python nor python2 will be added to the PATH by default without a manual brew link --force). We will maintain python2, python3 and python@3 aliases.

So to install Python 3, run the following command:

```
brew install python3
```

Then, the `pip` is installed automatically, and you can install any package by `pip install <package>`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm on Sierra. After doing those commands, it looked successful, but then `-bash: pip: command not found`. What did work for me was the top answer: `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: @iamse7en Did you restart Terminal or open another tab? What is the log after the postinstall command?

Comment: FWIW - I also had the `pip: command not found` message. I did try to open a new tab in iTerm and had the same message. No errors on either brew command.

Comment: I guess this will install python 3, and not pip.

Comment: for those where it didn't work, look for pip3 but not "pip" and maybe create an alias

Answer (score 21):

If you want "pip3" you can do the ff:

> via brew:
>   `brew install python3`

[image]

then you can execute

`pip3 <command> [options]`

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45666982/edit) (it covers text output and answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo port install py27-pip
```

Then update your PATH to include the *py27-pip* bin directory (you can add this in [~/.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example):

```
PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
```

pip will be available in a new terminal window.

Comment: `port` is not installed by default

Comment: The default shell was changed from [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) to [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) in [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Removed_or_changed_components) (Catalina, 2019).

Comment: this of course assumes MacPorts is installed; also, when using MacPorts, I'm using the (newer) version of `bash` (v5.2) that can be installed via `port` rather than the outdated version that comes w/ macOS (v3.2), assuming for whatever one doesn't want to run the default macOS shell (`zsh`) https://www.macports.org/install.php

Answer (score 12):

To install or upgrade **pip**, download **get-pip.py** from *[Installation - pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/)*

Then run the following:

`sudo python get-pip.py`

For example:

```
sudo python Desktop/get-pip.py

Password:
  Downloading/unpacking pip
  Downloading pip-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

```
sudo pip install pymongo

Password:
Downloading/unpacking pymongo
  Downloading pymongo-2.6.3.tar.gz (324kB): 324kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/0c/jb79t3bx7cz6h7p71ydhwb_m0000gn/T/pip_build_goker/pymongo/setup.py) egg_info for package pymongo

Installing collected packages: pymongo
...
```

Comment: Yes, but there are simpler methods

Comment: get-pip.py is about as simple as it gets

Answer (score 12):

Install Python 3 first, and then use pip3 to install packages.

```
brew install python
```

Python 3  will be installed, and pip is shipped with it. To use pip to install some package, run the following

```
pip3 install package
```

Notice it's pip3 because you want to use Python 3.

Answer (score 9):

## Install without the need for `sudo`

If you want to install `pip` without the need for `sudo`, which is always frustrating when trying to install packages globally, install `pip` in your local folder `/usr/local` like this:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/
```

and then:

`pip install <package-of-choice>` without `sudo`

Comment: pip install results in `ImportError: No module named pip._internal`

Comment: This fixes the ImportError @raarts mentioned:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997795/164545

Answer (score 8):

Download the Python setup tools from [the PyPI website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools):

Use the tar file.

Once you download, go to the downloaded folder and run

```
python setup.py install
```

Once you do that, you will have *easy_install*.

Use the below then to install pip:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: If you download the Mac installer packages from python.org, then pip is bundled in the installation. No need to run setup tools anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow easy install doesn't work on my old Mac ([10.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion)). This solves my problem:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

If you do not have wget, just open the URL in the browser, `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`, and then save as `get-pip.py`.

Answer (score -5):

I recommend Anaconda to you. It's the leading open data science platform powered by Python. There are many basic packages installed. Anaconda (`conda`) comes with its own installation of `pip`.

Comment: Not related to the question

Comment: @DonnyP Actually, this suggestion [addresses the question](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install) and would expeditiously solve the original problem  as it comes with `pip`.  This answer should be promoted and encouraged.

Comment: this is not an answer this is an advertisement.

If I'm mistaken the author should provide more details on how this addresses the question.

Comment: The question was how to install pip. If you recommend a product that already includes pip, then your answer (or suggestion) is not related to the question.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `conda` comes with `pip` installed already. It is preferable to just use a `conda` installation on your Mac than to use the other methods described that mess with direct system installations. Especially when it comes to Python, installing things with a bare-`pip` is a very bad idea. You should be using the `pip` that comes with `conda` instead to correctly isolate your package environments.