# Python can't find module NLTK

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, nltk

I followed these instructions http://www.nltk.org/install.html to install nltk module on my mac (10.6)
I have installed python 2.7, but when I open IDLE and type `import nltk` it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

The problem is the module is installed in another python version, 2.6. How can I install the package in python version 2.7? I tried some of the solutions suggested in various answers, for example I tried typing this in the terminal

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and then installed NLTK again with the command

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

but I get the message: Requirement already up-to-date in /Library/Python/2.6/. So apparently the command line `export PYTHONPATH` didn't do anything (it still tries to install the package in 2.6) OR (more likely) I didn't understand the meaning/functioning of that command line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apple ships its own version of Python with OS X, that's why pip gets confused. There are probably ways to install it to your python2.7 installation, but the good solution is using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642368/real-difficulty-installing-nltk-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Answer (score 60):

On OS X you could have multiple installation of Python, so investigate it first:

```
$ which python python2 python3
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ which pip pip2 pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

All within `/usr/bin` are built-in and all other in `/usr/local/bin` are external installed by Homebrew or some other package manager.

If you're using `pip` or `pip3` from `/usr/local`, then you've to use the same Python instance, otherwise they're different instances.

Just install it via `pip`:

```
pip install nltk
```

or for Python 3:

```
pip3 install nltk
```

then run the right Python instance from `/usr/local/bin` or update your `PATH` system variable.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you install the actual Python for Mac, not the one built into the console. Then, install pip by executing [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script. Then skip to part 3 of the instructions and go from there.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the following command worked for me. Try this!!

```
py -3 -m pip install nltk
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
pip install --user -U nltk
```

Answer (score 3):

On my mac I had two different versions of Python 3 installed: Python 3.6 and Python 3.7. I had installed `nltk` having Python 3.7 in my `$PATH`:

```
$ pip3 install nltk
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But `nltk` was missing for Python 3.6. Solution: install `nltk` also for version 3.6.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ pip3 install nltk
Collecting nltk
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/ed/9c755d357d33bc1931e157f537721efb5b88d2c583fe593cc09603076cc3/nltk-3.4.zip
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from nltk) (1.12.0)
Collecting singledispatch (from nltk)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/10/369f50bcd4621b263927b0a1519987a04383d4a98fb10438042ad410cf88/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: singledispatch, nltk
  Running setup.py install for nltk ... done
Successfully installed nltk-3.4 singledispatch-3.4.0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a virtualenv, but if you really want to use it from the terminal, I'd recommend adding your export statement to ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Just restart Jupyter Notebook or anything you are using after installing...
It works...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue an an Intel MacBook.

Fixed with

1. Make sure the python bin directory in the path

   - mine is `/Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.9/bin`
2. Restart the computer

NOTE that just restarting the terminal did NOT help

Answer (score 0):

VERY chaotic this post.
Let´s start by clearing some key points:

- OSX is 10.6 which means Python v2.71 (from Nov 2010)
- here is the installer, just in case:
  [Python v271](https://pythontest.com/python/installing-python-3-11/)
  [1](https://pythontest.com/python/installing-python-3-11/): https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/
- NLTK requires Python versions 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 or 3.11
  Check this out:
  [Installing Python 311 on OSX](https://pythontest.com/python/installing-python-3-11/)

Hope this helps!

LAO