# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ntlk'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, nltk

I am using PyCharm and Anaconda. I have installed NTLK with sudo `pip install -U nltk` and even to make sure since I'm on Mac OS and I saw [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947414/python-cant-find-module-nltk) to also try `pip3 install nltk`.

However, no matter where I try (PyCharm's terminal, Pycharm's Python, or my own terminal), I cannot get `import ntlk` to work and always get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ntlk'`.

The weird thing is that I actually manage to run some code with a simple "Python test.py" that contains: `from nltk.tag import StanfordPOSTagger` but whenever I try to `import ntlk` to be able to then `nltk.download('punkt')` I get the `No module named 'ntlk'` error.

Would you know where that is coming from?

Edit:

output of

1. python -V: Python 3.7.0
2. python3 -V: Python 3.7.0
3. pip -V: pip 18.0 from /Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
4. pip3 -V: pip 18.0 from /Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

As for `python3 -c "import ntlk; print('ntlk available')"` it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ntlk'
```

Edit 2:

Output of  `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))"`

/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/.../lib/python37.zip
/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7
/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages

Comment: Try running it `pip install -U nltk` from Anaconda prompt

Comment: @EricZhou That's I did, it's the first line of my question ;)

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but this is probably happening because you have 2 installations of python, an Anaocnda one and a non-Anaconda one. When you run pip outside of the Anaconda prompt, it installs to the non-Anaconda one, but when you run a program, it defaults to the Anaconda one, so the module doesn't show up. There was a good stackoverflow answer about this but I can't find it right now. (what I said might be wrong)

Comment: @EricZhou I tried that just in case and I got # All requested packages already installed from anaconda.

Comment: What are the outputs of `python -V`, `python3 -V`, `pip -V` and `pip3 -V`? What does `python3 -c "import ntlk; print('ntlk available')"` return?

Comment: @hoefling thanks for the comment. Please see my edit

Comment: Another question: what is the output of `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))" `?

Comment: I suspect your user's site packages dir (`/Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages`) is not in `sys.path`, so packages installed with `pip` are not visible to Python. However, I don't think `pip` and Anaconda coexist well - why don't you install packages with `conda install`? `conda install nltk` should work just fine.

Comment: Oh, and I often misspell the package, writing `ntlk` instead of `nltk`. Double-check you import the right name - maybe it's only a typo.

Comment: @hoefling additional edit to show the output. Tried onda install nltk and it still doesn't work

Comment: Looks like it's indeed the `sys.path` issue: try `PYTHONPATH=/Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages python -c "import nltk; print('nltk available')"`. This should be the same dir that is printed on `pip -V` command, but without the trailing `/pip` part.

Comment: @hoefling should I add anaconda3... to PYTHONPATH=/Users/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages ?

Comment: You mention that you installed NLTK into the Anaconda's env but you also mention that you used `sudo`. I am not familiar with Anaconda but it doesn't sound right to me as `sudo` will take you out of your environment so you should be installing into the system python. Try running `pip install nltk` from pycharm's terminal without using sudo. 
Also, you can check what python/pip is used by using the `which` command. `which python` and `which pip` should be in the same folder.

Comment: @RomanKutlak All of the commands I have typed were in PyCharm's terminal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your import code.

It's NLTK (i.e. `import nltk`) not `ntlk` =)