# Cannot Import NLTK (No other threads helping)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I keep getting this error when I am trying to import NLTK—

```
import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import nltk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

I am very new to this. I found a few similar answers, but I tried the solutions and they didn't work. The closest I got to was here—[Python can't find module NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947414/python-cant-find-module-nltk), however the last part the user mentions

Answer here—

> then run the right Python instance from /usr/local/bin or update your PATH system variable.

However, I have no idea what that means and how to do it.

[Here are my paths for python and pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmNS9.png), but I am not sure what to do after that. I am on a Mac.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you installed NLTK?

Comment: To install it run `pip install nltk`

Answer (score 0):

First you need install NLTK.

Execute in command prompt:

```
Pip install nltk
```

After you need download nltk packages:

in python console run this command:

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

And select the option "all" packages to download. When download finish you can use the nltk