# How to get rid of import nltk error on mac?

Tags: python, macos, nltk

I am running Python 2.7.2 on my mac.

I am getting an error for `import nltk`

namely this:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Please help.

Comment: This is far too vague to answer. Have you installed NLTK? Have you ensured it's visible inside your PYTHONPATH/`sys.path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do not have nltk.

"ImportError
Raised when an import statement fails to find the module definition or when a from ... import fails to find a name that is to be imported."
See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html

Try opening terminal and running:

```
pip install nltk
```

If you do not have pip installed take a look at:
[How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x)