# Python 3.3 and Installing PyOpenSSL on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyopenssl

I have python 3.3 working and can run some basic code (like `print("Hello World")`). Next I need so get PyOpenSSL set up. I've downloaded and unzipped the `pyOpenSSL-master.zip` from their github site, but I have no idea what to do with it next.

I moved the unzipped directory into `/libs`, cd into `/libs/pyopenssl-master` and did `python setup.py install --user`. But that failed with

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Other than the directory not existing, which I assume that the installer would create, the bigger problem is that it appears to be trying to write to the python 2.7 folder and I'm using 3.3.

If you can't tell, I'm pretty much out of my element. I've never installed a Python library before and I'm also not great with OSX installations. Can anyone help me get this set up? Thanks.

Comment: Can't. This is for a class that I'm taking and I have to use openSSL.

Comment: No I meant install PyOpenSSL using pip.

Comment: Oh sorry. I've never heard of pip. How do I use it?

Comment: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/

Comment: I just tried `sudo pip install pyopenssl` but I got `sudo: pip: command not found`

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it out.

Comment: You need to install pip; Please see the documentation

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like installing pip is more cryptic than installing pyopenssl.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Thank you again. It looks like the pyopenssl library doesn't do very much anyway, so I think I'm just going to explore making system calls instead.

Comment: `sudo pip install ...` is almost always a terrible idea.  You don't want to let Python installation software write to your system's library paths.  Python installation software usually makes a mess.  The best option seems to be to create a virtualenv and use pip to install things into that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can install pyOpenSSL on OS X (or just about any other platform):

1. Install pip

   1. Install it using a package for your operating system.  For example, if you use brew, `brew install pip`.
   2. If there is no package for your operating system, download https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
   3. Run it (probably as root, unfortunately): `sudo python get-pip.py`
2. Install virtualenv using pip - `pip install --user virtualenv`
3. Create a virtualenv to install pyOpenSSL into - `virtualenv ~/Environments/pyOpenSSL-stuff`
4. Activate the virtualenv - `. ~/Environments/pyOpenSSL-stuff/bin/activate`
5. Install pyOpenSSL with pip - `pip install pyopenssl`

At this point you have pyOpenSSL installed in a virtualenv.  Any time you want to use pyOpenSSL you'll need to activate the virtualenv.  I suggest that you actually create a virtualenv for each project of *yours* that you work on and install all of the necessary dependencies for each project into that project's virtualenv.

This does result in a lot of duplicate installations of packages.  Unfortunately this seems to be the state of the art for Python package installation.  Fortunately most Python packages are rather small.