# no module named rsi2 in python? cannot import through pip

Tags: python, pyalgotrade

I'm new to python, and trying to get a simple backtest to work using these examples [pyalgotrade examples](http://gbeced.github.io/pyalgotrade/docs/v0.20/html/tutorial.html) however when I try to run the line:

`import rsi2`

in an IPython Notebook I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rsi2'

Since every other import line works I'm not sure what I am missing. I tried:

- searching the python package documentation for rsi2, but nothing showed up
- searching StackOverflow, but none of these helped: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587457/importerror-no-module-named-python) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295895/python-no-module-named-serial-no-module-named-requests) (returned no matching distribution found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pyalgotrade examples you linked to include a block of code with the heading "Save this code as rsi2.py:".  This file is the `rsi2` that `import rsi2` is trying to import.  You need to save the given code as `rsi2.py` and store it in your working directory, next to any other files that contain "`import rsi2`".

Comment: Wow...... Thank you for that, I can't believe I missed something so obvious