# How to POST a local file using urllib2 in Python?

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

I am a complete Python noob and am trying to run cURL equivalents using urllib2. What I want is a Python script that, when run, will do the exact same thing as the following cURL command in Terminal:

```
curl -k -F docfile=@myLocalFile.csv http://myWebsite.com/extension/extension/extension
```

I found the following template on a tutorial page:

```
import urllib
import urllib2


url = "https://uploadWebsiteHere.com"
data = "{From: 'sender@email.com', To: 'recipient@email.com', Subject:   'Postmark test', HtmlBody: 'Hello dear Postmark user.'}"
headers = { "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Conthent-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Postmark-Server-Token": "abcdef-1234-46cc-b2ab-38e3a208ab2b"}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

but I am completely lost on the 'data' and 'headers' vars. The urllib2 documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) defines the 'data' input as "a string specifying additional data to send to the server" and the 'headers' input as "a dictionary". I am totally out of my depth in trying to follow this documentation and do not see why a dictionary is necessary when I could accomplish this same task in terminal by only specifying the file and URL. Thoughts, please?

Comment: You should consider using python-requests instead: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/. As it says at the top of its homepage "Python’s standard urllib2 module provides most of the HTTP capabilities you need, but the API is thoroughly broken. It was built for a different time — and a different web. It requires an enormous amount of work (even method overrides) to perform the simplest of tasks".

Comment: I looked into that but couldn't even download "pip" to download requests. When I ran the "python get-pip.py" command in Terminal, I got an error saying that the file doesn't even exist (even though I downloaded it).

Comment: Without having `pip` installed, you will not go very far in Python. Resolve this very basic prerequisity first.

Comment: On the assumption that you're on Mac OS, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x) might help ... @JanVlcinsky is right; you need pip.

Comment: Thanks, @ZeroPiraeus! But now when I run "pip install requests" in Terminal, I get the error "Storing debug log for failure in /Users/ME/Library/Logs/pip.log"

Comment: ... well, once you've read that log, you'll either know how to resolve the problem or have the basis for a new SO question :-) ... (possibly you need `sudo pip install requests`, but I'm not a Mac person).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Never mind, I fixed it (used "$ sudo easy_install requests").

Comment: Most HTTP headers are not required. You could probably get away with using an empty dictionary.

Comment: related: [How to send a “multipart/form-data” with requests in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are posting doesn't appear to be valid JSON. Assuming the server is expecting valid JSON, you should change that.

Your `curl` invocation does not pass any optional headers, so you shouldn't need to provide much in the request. If you want to verify the exact headers you could add `-vi` to the `curl` invocation and directly match them in the Python code. Alternatively, this works for me:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://localhost:8888/"
data = '{"From": "sender@email.com", "To": "recipient@email.com", "Subject": "Postmark test", "HtmlBody": "Hello dear Postmark user."}'
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

It probably is in your best interest to switch over to using `requests`, but for something this simple the standard library `urllib2` can be made to work.

Comment: this code doesn't emulate the `curl` command from the question

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is a Python script that, when run, will do the exact same thing as the following cURL command in Terminal:

```
$ curl -k -F docfile=@myLocalFile.csv https://myWebsite.com/extension...
```

`curl -F` sends the file using `multipart/form-data` content type. You could reproduce it easily using `requests` library:

```
import requests # $ pip install requests

with open('myLocalFile.csv','rb') as input_file:
    r = requests.post('https://myWebsite.com/extension/...', 
                      files={'docfile': input_file}, verify=False)
```

`verify=False` is to emulate `curl -k`.