# When i import parse in ipython , computer say 'parse' it not defined

Tags: parsing, ipython

I think i don't have parse library. So, Where can i get it?

As beginner, I need your help.

I wrote from lxml.html import parse , Computer say name 'parse' is not defined

Comment: Which OS do you use? In general: The more information you provide the easier it is for others to help you.
With that said, I think you are looking for https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.5

Answer (score 0):

You actually probably need the `lxml` package, which was in the comment by cel. It seems to me like your question is concerning how to actually install the package. Everything at PyPi (the Python package index) can be installed in several ways. For me, the easiest is using [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), which is a tool for installing Python packages. Here are some links for how to get pip on your machine for different operating systems: [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows), [Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x), or [in general](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Once you have `pip` installed, you go to your command line and type

```
pip install ['package_name']
```

where, in your case, `package_name` would be `lxml`. Once you do that, your import should work just fine. The full pip documentation is [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/).

If you prefer to manually install the package, you can download the source and install it according to the Python docs for Python [2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) or [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html).