# Python geopy install

Tags: python, geopy

I am trying to install Geopy in Python. How do I do this in really simple terms? I have Python 3.4.0 launcher installed. Where do I write the Geopy install command? On a text file with a .py extension? Or in Terminal? I have read to ways to install Geopy, using easy-install and pip. Which one should I use? 
Below is one example I have read:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/lib/pythonX.Y, where X.Y is the Python version, and press Enter.
easy_install-X.Y package, where package is the name of the package to install, and press Enter.
```

Below is another installation I have read:

```
pip install geopy

>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
>>> print(location.address)
Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...
>>> print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
(40.7410861, -73.9896297241625)
>>> print(location.raw)
{u'place_id': u'9167009604', u'type': u'attraction', ...}
```

So, in the above code, where am I writing this, because this is printing the result upon request? In Terminal? I have the Python launcher but I can't seem to write a new script within it, it just loads text files with the .py extension.

Apologies for the asking about the basics here. Very much a novice. If anyone could explain how I could install Geopy and execute the above geocoding technique in a step-by-step way, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have pip installed (as miles mentioned), in terminal, type:

```
pip install geopy
```

Then you should be able to use the geopy module in python. Try from terminal

```
python
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help from yourself and @miles82. The above advice has returned this: Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin; pip install geopy; File "<stdin>", line 1 pip install geopy ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax; -m pip install geopy; File "<stdin>", line 1 -m pip install geopy ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax; -m ensurepip; File "<stdin>", line 1 -m ensurepip ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax; pip install geopy; File "<stdin>", line 1 pip install geopy SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Enter the commands in terminal, looks like you are trying to enter them in the python interpreter?

Comment: This was in Terminal. First, I typed 'python', which loaded the first line pasted above.

Comment: It says Python 2.7.5 above. But when I launch the Python Launcher it's 3.4.0. So maybe pip isn't pre-installed in 2.7.5?

Comment: If i go ahead and just type 'pip install geopy' as soon as the Terminal opens (without first typing 'python') then it returns: Macintosh:~ user$ pip install geopy
-bash: pip: command not found

Comment: To clarify, when I am saying terminal, I mean before typing 'python'. pip is not pre-installed with 2.7. See the following to install pip on mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x . Then attempt again.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.4 comes with pip so you should be able to do the following in the command line:

```
python -m pip install geopy
```

If that doesn't work, try running this first:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Comment: Thanks for the help from yourself and @KieranBristow. The above advice has returned this: Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
pip install geopy
File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install geopy              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-m pip install geopy
File "<stdin>", line 1
-m pip install geopy         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
-m ensurepip
File "<stdin>", line 1
-m ensurepip               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
pip install geopy
File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install geopy
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's because you started Python 2.7 which doesn't bundle pip like 3.4 does (and you obviously have both versions installed). Glad you got it working after all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to install on windows. This is how I have done.
Prerequisite: pip ([Else find here, how to install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows))

1. Step 1: Run cmd as Administrator
2. Step 2: cd ..
3. Step 3: cd .. // you're now in root
4. Step 4: pip install geopy

Though it's been late to answer. Hope it helps somebody.

[image: This is how you see it]