# pip: command not found

Tags: python, pip

I encounter a problem when installing pip for python2.7. I downloaded the file get-pip.py, and install it successfully:

```
bogon:haha itensb$ python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

But when I run the command pip, I got:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

I think it is the PATH not set appropriatelly , But I new on Mac. I need your help , thanks!

Comment: What does `which pip` give you?

Comment: nothing shows~ @inspectorG4dget

Comment: @AdemÖztaş: OP is on mac - `apt-get` is not an option

Comment: do `ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Do you see a `pip` in the output?

Comment: Yes ==> README   pip   pip-1.5.6.dist-info @inspectorG4dget

Comment: do `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`. Do you see `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` in the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65557/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-itenyh).

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please remember to select it as the best answer

Answer (score 5):

Use `python -m pip`. If you want the `pip` command check out @user3282276's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your PATH variable is not set to include the location that pip was installed to. On Macs and other *nix like operating systems when you type a command in the command line, what is actually happening is the shell is trying to find the executable file in a predefined area, called the PATH variable. If you are interested check out this question, https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them.

You are able to see what yours is set to if you do this in your command line

```
echo $PATH
```

this will give you some file paths separated by colons, for example when I type the command above I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/Android Dev Tool/sdk/tools
```

which means that my shell will check for a executable in each of these files, if it finds it, it will run otherwise it will tell you the program can't be found. As a side note this is the reason why when you run an executable not in one of these PATH files you must do,

```
./program
```

this is specifying a relative path to the executable file, the current directory that you are in.

So for you, you installed pip to this directory:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

chances are the above echo statement did not include this file, if it did then you have another problem. What you need to do is to update your PATH variable to include this directory as well. To do this you add an export statement to your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` on Linux) in your home directory (this is a hidden file) that includes your current path variables (so you will still be able to run everything installed in the proper place) and this new directory that you installed pip to. To do this add this line to the end of your `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

and you should be good to go. However before it will take effect you need to close and open your terminal window again or run `source .bash_profile`. You can verify this worked by running the `echo` command above, it should return the same thing but this time with /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages appended to the end.

Note: By the way the `which` command that you were told to run in the comments locates a program within the users path, which is why it did not return anything to you. Also since you will probably run into this soon enough there is also a variable called `PYTHONPATH` (look [here](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath)) which tells python where to look to import modules. You should set this to whatever directory you have pip installing modules to if it is not already set.

Answer (score 2):

Install python3 first, then use pip3 to install packages.

> brew install python

python3 will be installed, and pip is shipped with it. To use pip to install some package, run the following

> pip3 install package

Notice it's pip3 because you want to use python3.

My same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-to-install-pip-on-mac-os-x/42066678#42066678)

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42066678/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Answer (score 1):

to run the command, it works

```
sudo easy_install pip
```