# pip: command not found (OS X) - editing bash_profile doesn't work

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have installed Python 2.7 on Mac and installed pip (with the eventual goal of installing python-swiftclient: https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/integration/python-swiftclient.html )

Unfortunately I get the error "command not found" on using pip.

I have followed the instructions in this thread: [pip: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119934/pip-command-not-found) I added export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (I verified that this is the correct path) to .bash_profile and ran the source command.

Pip is still not being found.

Anyone know a solution? (Keep in mind this is my first foray into installing python and doing command line stuff. I'm not a born unix user so installing packages and such is pretty new to me...)

Thanks!

Comment: How is your Python installed? How did you install `pip`?

Comment: Any chance you "upgraded" to Yosemite after you installed Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

When I use python on Mac, I simply install Anaconda, which is shipped with pip. So maybe you could use that.
[Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `python -m pip` until you get this resolved (or forever if you want :P)