# SyntaxError: invalid syntax wheninstalling pip on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I have installed pip according to instructions on pip website. Downloaded get-pip.py and insatlled it with `python get-pip.py`. Got a confirmation saying installation is successful. Apparently the moment i type pip i get following error:

```
    [fh-mi-sdb99-ma:~/Downloads] sdb99% pip
/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py:211: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 271, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2174, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1907, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 211
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i am not sure why is this happening.. 
Any suggestion that would help me to get pip installed correctly on my mac?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
[fh-mi-sdb99-ma:~/Downloads] sdb99% python --version
Python 2.7.9
[fh-mi-sdb99-ma:~/Downloads] sdb99% pip --version
/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py:211: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 271, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2174, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1907, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 211
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Second EDIT:

I have installed python 3.5 pkg but still when i type python on terminal, python 2.7 is initiated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing pip on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Did you install as sudo? I'm not sure if it is required, but without sudo, you may not have overwritten an original `pip` file that was using python2.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stack trace indicates that you are actually running `python2.5`

#### Verification

To verify your python version run `python --version`.

I would also verify your pip version by running `pip --version`.

#### Using the correct python

If you already installed python2.7, you can often specify it specifically, for example: `python2.7 my_module.py`. Try typing `python` in your terminal and tap <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice. This will list all the python* programs you have in your path. If python2.7 is not listed, you will need to [install](https://www.python.org/downloads/) it.

#### Using the correct pip

Similar to the above about using the correct python, you should ensure you are using the correct pip.
Try typing `pip` into your terminal and tap <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice. This will list any extra pip versions you have. It is often easier to specify `pip2.7`.

#### Download and install Python3.4

If you haven't made a firm decision between python2 and python3, a nice feature of python3 is that python3.4 is bundled with pip, so you don't have to do anything to use it.

Comment: see the edit. i have typted both your suggestions and giving you outcome of that in edit

Comment: I have installed python3.5 through installer from python website.. but stil when i type python on terminal i get python 2.7.9

Comment: Have you tried the `TAB` trick mentioned above? It should list multiple versions of python. If it doesn't I would reinstall python, and be sure to use superuser privileges.

Comment: yes i tried that but no other version of python is listed when i press TAB for two times ..

Comment: If only one `python` is listed in your path, and (based on your edit to the question), you `python --version` lists `Python 2.7.9` then I would have to conclude that you did not install python3 fully or correctly. I would try reinstalling it.

Comment: would you recommend installing it again by installer or throughh comman dprompt

Comment: I would download the '.pkg' file for `Python 3.4.3`. It will walk you through the install process, prompting for your password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76664/discussion-between-amccormack-and-tryeverylanguage).

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Python 2 is end-of-life. Python 3.4+ comes with pip

### Original Answer

You are using Python 2.5, outdated version:

```
   /Library/Python/2.5/
```

Please install at least Python 2.7 first:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: when i type python --version it gives me Python 2.7.9

Comment: try `which pip` and then you see `pip` command you run is not probably against Python 3.7. You probably need to reinstall Python, reinstall pip and make sure pip gets installed against the correct Python. If needed, use full path to start python, eg. `/usr/local/bin/python`