# Installing numpy/matplotlib/etc. on Mac

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am very new to python, and am having difficulty getting any packages from online to install properly. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but since I am new to language I am unsure of what it is. I have read through several online sources but still can't get it to work. I feel really dumb asking this, but I would greatly appreciate it if someone could walk me through how to install it starting from the point of downloading the package online. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your primary use case is the scipy stack, for example as a Matlab replacement. I would highly recommend using the Anaconda distribution. It is brilliant for new comers, a large majority of what you are likely after comes pre installed.

Download it here:
https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_macosx

I would recommend picking the python 3 64bit installer. A direct link to the download is here: 
https://3230d63b5fc54e62148e-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda3-2.3.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Homebrew as your general package manager and then use use it to install Pip to manage all of your python packages.  Both of the links below will walk you through how to do these things.

See [Homebrew link](http://brew.sh/)
See [How to install pip on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x) for Pip

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) and download `get-pip.py`

Then, from terminal run the command `python get-pip.py`

This should install pip for you.  Pip is awesome, and you really want to have it.  Now, all you have to do is run this command from terminal:

`pip install matplotlib`

Or to get Numpy:

`pip install numpy`