# How to get into the python directory

Tags: python, macos, pip

### objective

Install **pip**. But I need to install a few other dependencies on my mac. I need to check a few things in the python directory.

### Background

This would seem simple enough. I am following along to a tutorial http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-install-pip/

I am currently at the part of the tutorial where they have you

> 4)Verify that easy_install is inside Scripts sub-folder - See more at: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-install-pip/#sthash.ZKCMs26K.dpuf

But now they want me to

> go to your Python directory (where you installed Python) and open the Scripts sub-folder. Look inside it and make sure that you can see easy_install – an executable file.

The tutorial is aimed for PC users. I am on a mac. I found the python directory by running

```
which python
```

which gave me the result

[image]

Comment: That tutorial provides some pretty outdated information - you should follow the [official `pip` install directions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/) to install it - you don't have to actually use setuptools directly anymore. To answer your immediate question, though - `which` locates the executable program in a path, and `/usr/bin` generally only stores executable files. The real path to where the default `python` installation is on a Mac is: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/(version)/lib`.

Comment: @birryree ok i managed to get pip installed by just following the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x . so wondering if I should remove the question or edit it to be useful if someone does need to get into the python directory