# What is get-pip.py checksum? Where can I get it for sure?

Tags: python, macos, pip

It looks strange, that the `pip` documentation (here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) tells "To install pip, **securely** download get-pip.py", but there is no checksum to check if I downloaded the good `get-pip.py` file.

It's recommended to use package manager like `apt` or `yum`, but what can I do on Mac?

So the question is where can I obtain checksum of `get-pip.py` to download it via `wget`, to check that it's okay (check it's integrity, that the file isn't corrupted or modified during transmission) and to install it on my Mac?

Comment: `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro I know. But it means, that the official documentation is broken?

Comment: Checksum is not used to check the version of the file. It is used to check the integrity of the downloaded file. Just download the file from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py). Make user the URL contains `https` (HTTP secure) when downloading.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro changed question a bit. Yes, I need a checksum to check it's integrity. Containing `https` in the URL isn't enough. I don't ever know if `wget` supports SSL, and btw it uses OpenSSL, which may contain bugs.

In the bad world you can't trust your browser and/or `curl` or `wget`, that's why I ask about checksum.

For example, when you run `easy_install` it checks MD5 hash of transmitted file. Why can't I do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download pip [directly from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/), either in source or wheel form, and use either the MD5 hash or the PGP signature provided there.

Comment: It's exactly what I asked about! It's so obvious, but it slipped from my mind

Answer (score 0):

The checksum of `pip` is located on the corresponding PyPi page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/

You can download it from there directly or use `sudo easy_install pip` in order to install it via `easy_install` if possible.

Comment: You posted the exact link which I posted... You changed your question a bit, then answered it yourself and accepted your own answer instead of mine. That's not cool.

Comment: @taleinat Please accept my appologies! I just wanted to mention installation method using easy_install.

Comment: I see that your intentions were good, and you marked my answer as accepted again, so it's fine :)