# Wrong pip running

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip

some time ago i installed pip probably according to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x).
Later on i installed everything by `macports`.
I have now installed Python 3.X and i installed py3x-pip. Installed; Activated.
Even run `port select --set pip pip3x` serval times. 
But nothing open the pip3. Only the previous installed pip.

```
name:~ Jee-Bee$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
name:~ Jee-Bee$ /usr/local/bin/pip -V
pip 7.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
name:~ Jee-Bee$ pip -V
pip 7.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

1. What have can i do to delete the `easy_install` pip? and maybe other software(?).
2. How get i the pip3 running?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with patching the system python unless you *need* the objective C bindings sine that path is a) more work b) more fragile. Much easier to handle things in a [virtual environment like done here](http://grahamgilbert.com/blog/2016/01/05/dynamic-first-boot-scripts-with-imagr-and-flask/). If thats more work for you with no added benefit, another easier option than debugging what broke in ports (or what you're not getting about your setup) would be to skip macports and use [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install python3
```

You'll have python and easy_install set for pip3, python version 3 and have things nicely set up in /usr/local/bin with better diagnostics and hand holding if $PATH (and other common gotchas) break your setup.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it is system. i have onced installed pip using `easy_install pip` and i want to removed that version. 
Just install `homebrew` is not the solution since i have to remove everything from `macports` and `easy_install`.
Firts remove `easy_install` pip and reinstall pip using `macport`. if that doesn't work i can try `homebrew`.

Comment: That's not entirely try about having to remove @Jan-Bert . Homebrew would 1) add `pip3` in your path with the python3 install 2) have better diagnostics and help so you wouldn't need to work through what went amiss with MacPorts which lacks said help. You would be free to keep using all the ports you have as brew/ports are not mutually exclusive.