# Install pip on OS X

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, pip

I want to install pip  on OS X
So I downloaded and install Python 3.4, and afterwards, Install pip by using the script provided by the Python Packaging Authority; but when I run pip I got a **command not found**

```
MacBook-Pro-de-paquirrin:Home paquirrin$ sudo curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1487k  100 1487k    0     0   783k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  783k
MacBook-Pro-de-paquirrin:Home paquirrin$ sudo python3 get-pip.py
The directory '/Users/paquirrin/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/paquirrin/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 718kB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 1.6MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 6.0.8
    Uninstalling pip-6.0.8:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-6.0.8
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1 wheel-0.29.0
MacBook-Pro-de-paquirrin:Home paquirrin$ sudo pip install awsebcli
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Comment: Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Solution without using brew: sudo easy_install pip

Comment: mostly pip are auto-installed while python installation.

`pip2 install <your_module_name>` should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You install your `pip` locally. Try `bin/pip` from within the folder you did the `curl` command.

Answer (score 20):

Easiest way i found was using home-brew, it install all basic python and pip too. But feel free to use macports too.

```
brew install python
```

I used the answers from the post, if you need more help: [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Best answer, after trying making alias, brew install python, sudo python get-pip.py is sudo easy_install pip