# fixing mac preinstalled python

Tags: python, macos

Recently I try to install some package or update the pip, similar error message pops out.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File `enter code here`"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip'
```

I think that might due to an improper uninstallation of python on macport cause it, as when I try to change different python with the use of

```
port select --list python
```

and

```
sudo port select --set "python name"
```

and when I type

```
which python
```

all of them leads to

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

none of them connected to the Frameworks. 
I wanna ask is there anyway to restore the mac preinstalled python?

Comment: So what does `port select list python` show (update your question with the output)?  Also the error shows you are attempting to update a system file in `/Library`, which is wrong.  Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/installing-pip-on-mac-os-x)?

Comment: http://johnlaudun.org/20150512-installing-and-setting-pip-with-macports/
you can try

Comment: @Droppy when I type port select --list python these shows up 
        none
 python26-apple
 python27 (active)
 python27-apple
but all of them just connected to /opt/local/bin/python .

Comment: @Desrif, I have try the link previously but it just does not work.

Comment: @Droppy I have tried the link and reinstalled pip as shown in the link.
But the same error pops up when I try to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved simply by running

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```