# Trying to use python 2.7 when 3.5 is default

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently I can use py2.7 by using a terminal alias. My problem is that when I try and run a script, it depends on a module `requests`. I have tried to pip install this and even download the `requests2.7` folder and `sudo python setup.py install`. Even though I was aliased with python2.7, This resulted in it being downloaded to my python 3.5 site.

`Installed /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for requests==2.7.0
Finished processing dependencies for requests==2.7.0`

How can I fix this? I need to run scripts as 2.7 but my default seems to be 3.5.

Comment: you should have `pip2` to install modules for Python 2, and `pip3` to install modules for Python 3. Or you can use `python2 -m pip install requests`

Comment: try pip2.7 install requests

Comment: @furas After I command `python2.7 -m...` i get the error `no module named install. Or, how can I install pip2?

Comment: `no module named install` ? it seems you use `-m install` but you should `-m pip install`

Comment: Python 2.7 should have `pip2` installed. Did you try to use `pip2` in terminal` ?

Comment: @furas That was probably it, but now I get the error `no module pip`. I tried [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip) installation guide for pip but I got the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip` when I ran `get-pip.py`

Comment: Oh and yes I tried `pip2`

Comment: I don't know - maybe it need `setuptools`. What system do you use ? Windows/Linux/Mac ?

Comment: @furas I use a Mac

Comment: I use Linux and has `apt` to install different program - and there is `python-pip` for old Python. As I know you should have `brew` and maybe there is something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-to-install-pip-on-mac-os-x