# Attempting to split video into image array for use in ImageTk

Tags: python, image, opencv, tkinter

how do I split a video into individual frames so that I can use it in ImageTk.

I have found a few tutorials around this, but all the dependencies have since updated and I'm having real trouble finding a way to get this to work.
Many of the problems are from not being able to install the dependencies (OpenCV)

any suggestions on how I can install OpenCV to make this work:

```
import cv2
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.94:554/stream3")


while True:
    # get frame by frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite('pic.png',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

or what would you recommend I do?

Comment: on Linux Ubuntu/Mint you may need to use `apt install python-opencv` instead of using `pip`

Comment: currently Python use `opencv 3.x` and your example use `opencv 2.x`

Comment: there is also `SimpleCV` (which probably use `PyGame`) or you can try to use `PyGame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `pip` installed on your system. See [how to install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and [how to install pip on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-to-install-pip-on-mac-os-x)

Then just run `pip install opencv-python`