# No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'

Tags: python, macos, pip

I had pip installed earlier on my OSX, but its not working somehow. So, i was trying to install pip again, using the command :

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

But it gives me the error as below :

```
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
```

I am neither able to use pip, nor install it.

Comment: Have you tried this http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/06/14/-usr-bin-pip-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40950280/3141502

Comment: Yes, I did check http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/06/14/-usr-bin-pip-no-such-file-or-directory  but when I try and check `which pip`, i dont get any response, so I think pip is not there somehow on my system. And i am unable to install it as well.

Comment: Same issue here. Answers below dont help

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just run:
`$ hash -r`
in bash and it will be solved.

Comment: THANK YOU THIS WORKED FOR ME March 2020

Comment: There's no man page for this command, but it does work in some cases -- it updates the bash path hash, which sometimes gets stale under pyenv.  
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/hash.htm

Answer (score 53):

In my case, I had to upgrade pip from 22.1.2 to 22.2.1:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by removing the pip file in `/usr/local/bin` and reinstalling pip.

Answer (score 1):

Find your pip binary using this:

```
which pip or which pip3.7
```

then copy to below path:

```
sudo cp /home/LOGGED_USER/.local/bin/pip3.7 /usr/bin/pip3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the "No such file or directory" error was to add to $PATH the directory, where the 'pip' (and 'pip3') commands are installed. In your case such directory might be '/usr/local/bin/pip'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `python3 pip` but the working command was `pip3`