# I can not install anything using sudo apt-get install

Tags: installation, apt-get

For example when I try to install libnlopt-dev, it gives the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev
[sudo] password for burcak: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

When I try to dist-upgrade, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

And also sudo dpkg --configure -a gives the following error:

```
   $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python-gpgme (0.3-1.1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-gpgme (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
     apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
      Package apport is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-gobject-2 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up python-cairo (1.8.8-2) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-cairo (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up python-lockfile (1:0.12.2-1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-lockfile (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up python-pil:amd64 (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of asymptote:
     asymptote depends on python-pil; however:
      Package python-pil:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package asymptote (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-dropbox:
     nautilus-dropbox depends on python-gpgme; however:
      Package python-gpgme is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package nautilus-dropbox (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2:
     python-gtk2 depends on python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1); however:
      Package python-cairo is not configured yet.
     python-gtk2 depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3); however:
      Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pil.imagetk:amd64:
     python-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python-pil (= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1); however:
      Package python-pil:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package python-pil.imagetk:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     python-gpgme
     apport-gtk
     python-gobject-2
     python-cairo
     python-lockfile
     python-pil:amd64
     asymptote
     nautilus-dropbox
     python-gtk2
     python-pil.imagetk:amd64
```

My python version is Python 3.5.2. But I have also python 2.7 installed
**$sudo apt install -f** also did not work.

```
$sudo apt install -f
```

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions proposed here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

Comment: @David Gay Yes I tried but it did not work.