# Using cx_Freeze on a Mac

Tags: python, cx-freeze

My goal is to deploy an application I developed in python. I have a mac and I am trying to download cx_Freeze from:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=5.0.2#downloadsenter

When I download cx_Freeze, it tells me that I have to select an application to run the program. So, I tried selecting Idle because I used python to develop the app. However, it continuously fails to decode the download.

I have a setup script written in python and saved as setup.py in my applications folder.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
base = None
if sys.platform == 'Win32' : base = 'Win32GUI'
setup( name ='Bid Score Calculator',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'Bid Score Calculator',
       author = 'Brian Haney',
       options = {'build_exe': opts },
       executables = [Executeable( 'Bid Draft Interface.py', base= base)])
```

Ultimately, I am unsure of how to deploy my application. My questions are 1) What application supports a cx_Freeze download? 2) How do I use the setup script, to deploy the app.

Thanks in advance for any help or comments- I really appreciate it.

Disclaimer - I have been trying to use cx_Freeze for going on two hours, I have read and researched online and have been unable to find anything that helps. Further, I believe an answer to this question will serve a wide audience.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to check out [this page](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/). Obviously it will not open with the IDLE since it is stored to be installed.  What you really need at this stage is to open up a terminal in the dictionary where your whl file (in other words cx_Freeze) was installed and run:

```
python36 -m pip install somepackagename.whl
```

DO NOT RENAME.

OR

You could just run:

```
python36 -m pip install cx_Freeze
```

which will download and install for you.

---

Your setup script looks fine except you have not defined `opts` in the script.

Comment: Thanks for you help Simon. Your advice was definitely a step in the right direction. I read the page you sent. When I go to my command terminal and enter (python --version) the response is python 2.7.10. So, I went to the python webpage and downloaded the latest version, python 3.6, the installation on my computer was listed as successful. However, when i type (python --version) in my terminal, the reading is still 2.7.10. Additionally, when I type (pip --version) in the terminal, the response is command not found. Thus, I am unsure of how to proceed. Thanks again for you help!!

Comment: @BrianHaney How about `python36 --version`.  You have both the integrated version of Python plus the one you installed.

Comment: @BrianHaney  You will also need to install pip (named `pip36` once installed).  [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)  tells you how to do it.

Comment: If `python36`, `python3.6` cannot be found you may need to add it to path,  but that should not be necessary.

Comment: Each Python version installed will have  its version number followed  by `python`

Comment: So, I am getting further. I have both pip and cx_Freeze downloaded. However, when I type 'pip install 'program name'' into the command prompt, it responds 'could not find version that satisfies the requirement program name (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for program name

Comment: How do I create a version that satisfies the requirement?

Comment: @BrianHaney The problem is that you are using the pip for Python 2.7.  Try running `which pip` to make sure I am correct.  Unless you have not yet installed pip for 3.6 and you installed for 2.7 by mistake then `python36 -m pip install cx_Freeze` should work.