# installing pip and other libs using easy)install fails due to SSL

Tags: python, pip, nose, easy-install

Trying to get pip and some other utils on my newly wiped MacBookPro.

Trying to run distribute_setup.py fails with 403:SSL required; on some dependencies:

```
DNS-hosting:~ User1$ sudo python distribute_setup.py
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 485, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 480, in main
    tarball = download_setuptools()
  File "distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Found a workaround that supposed to work, but also fails on other dependencies: (nose/tornado; which I'm also unable to install)

```
DNS-hosting:~ User1$ sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
Password:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1622k  100 1622k    0     0  1071k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1071k
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /var/folders/r7/80znqn9d7jv6qf1wfbxcd_kw0000gn/T/tmpKFvgml/pip.zip (10.0.0)
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
```

Comment: There was a solution somewhere that said to uninstall/re-install easy_install. So now I'm unable to get that installed back on my mac too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

Comment: pip install has changed and requires SSL since October 2017. So any reference to installing it prior to that date is invalid. The simple commands like:

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you maintain a separate installation of Python, so you're not using the system installation and potentially mucking up your dependencies.

This can be easily achieved with Brew:

#### Brew (https://brew.sh)

Install:
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

#### Python 3.x

`brew install python --reinstall` which will install/reinstall Python 3.6.x

#### Python 2.7.x

`brew install python@2`

If you're set on using the local system version, you should be able to reinstall via:  `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: I will probably build it out using virtualenv to separate it from my original mac lib. but I still needed a working installer, going to try the brew install you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your timing is good, because pip v10.0.0 was released today.

Get the wheel:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/62/a1/0d452b6901b0157a0134fd27ba89bf95a857fbda64ba52e1ca2cf61d8412/pip-10.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=be3e30acf78a44cd750bf2db0912c701
```

Use the wheel to install the wheel:

```
python pip-10.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip install pip-10.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```