# problems with pip install mac OS X

Tags: python, shell, command-line, terminal, pip

Im trying to install a library for python 2.7 on mac

so i enter the command:

```
python -m pip install pyttsx
```

and the answer was `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

so i tried this to prove that pip exist

[image]

and it shows me that pip exist, so where is pip and why terminal says me that pip doesn't exist?
How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

Comment: no bro i already install pip but the terminal says me that pip doesn't exist

Comment: Screenshots shows python 3.4.3 version. So pip isn't installed for python v2.7 but 3.4.3. You can try `python3 -m pip install pyttsx`