# OS X: Multiple version of python 2.7.X

Tags: python-2.7

In order to install the Python module hidapi: I installed python 2.7 with home-brew:

```
brew install python2
```

I think it installed 2.7.15. Python information:

```
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I believe 2.7.10 was already installed (Apple OEM?).

The OS X command:

```
pip install hidapi
```

Indicates:

> Requirement already satisfied: hidapi in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.7.99.post21) Requirement
>   already satisfied: setuptools>=19.0 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hidapi) (39.1.0)

Attempts to import HID from the Python command line results in error:

```
>>> import hid
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: No module named hid

There may be more than one version of 2.7 installed (2.7.15?).

1. How can I test if a newer (second Python instance of 2.7.X) was installed today?
2. How can I invoke Python 2.7.15 if was installed today?
3. How can 2.7.10 be granted visibility to the hid module?

It I can invoke Python 2.7.15 and try to import the hid module, that should inch the troubleshooting process along.

## UPDATE

```
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ python2
```

Python 2.7.15 (default, May  1 2018, 16:44:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import hid
>>>
```

ONLY 2.7.15 has 'hid' visibility: the other two versions return an error.

```
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.15
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.10
```

All pip references lead to the same place:

```
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ pip -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ pip2 -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
Users-MacBook-Air:~ user$ pip2.7 -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: `python2.7 -V`?

Comment: By the way, Homebtew python is confusing. Try pyenv instead https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: @cricket_007 Excellent question. End of OP updated with results

Comment: Cool, and, `which pip`? Probably different from `pip2` or `pip2.7`?

Comment: @cricket_007  OP updated with pip responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've figured out the other questions, but

> How can 2.7.10 be granted visibility to the hid module

[You would need to install it using `pip` via `easy_install`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17271319/2308683) however adding libraries into your system Python is usually frowned upon, which is why virtualenv's exist, but, you would need to install that module as well

Besides that, Python3 should generally be used for any new Python development

Comment: Please elaborate the reasoning behind the Python3 statement.  For some reason, I am pointed to 2.7.  The effort is appreciated: thanks!

Comment: Python3 has been available for years and any library that hasn't upgraded yet should probably be avoided. https://pythonclock.org