# Installing pip using easy_install on Mac OS

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am trying to install `pip` through `easy_install`. I have tried the following command but no success:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip
```

Result:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

I have also tried simpler version `sudo easy_install pip` but getting same error.

I have tried many online solutions but still no success.

Comment: What version Python do you have?  `pip` is included in Python binary for versions 3.4 and above, so I assume your version is lower.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 9):

The easy solution is download and install the latest version of Python 3. Just grab the dmg from the website https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/
Verify it was installed.

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0
```

Pip is automatically included in this version so update it. Note use pip3 for Python 3.x

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip 
 Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
 Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

I am running a fairly clean install of 10.13.6 High Sierra. Only developer options installed are command line tools, python 3, and R. No Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply try running these in your terminal

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

then

```
python get-pip.py
```

then

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

try to see if this works

from https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: I get the error "ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead." on the second step: " python get-pip.py

Comment: only the first two steps worked for me on macOS 12.3 and I could use pip.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have tried installing Python via Homebrew, It should install pip for you aswell.

[How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

Comment: There's an issue. Now when I want to use `pip` , it says `pip: command not found`.

Comment: could you also state the current version of python installed please!

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `pip3` after installing latest Python 3.x