# how to delete the python module from the anacoda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

at first, I downloaded the python3.7.0 from the official website. at this time, when I enter python in cmd, it pops up and shows the 3.7.0. And I need the conda, I try pip3 install conda (pip does not work because it may be the python3.7.0), somehow, when I enter python in cmd, it turns out to be python 2.7?? and I went to the anaconda website, I install the anaconda package, at this time when I enter python in cmd, it turns out to be python 3.6.5. by this time, I have 3 python, I want to remove all other python except the 3.7.0. I tried to use anaconda to remove the python3.6.5, it failed. what to do?
My computer is MAC

[image: Error of anaconda]

Comment: Why are you installing so many pythons? Use the Anaconda installer if you want Anaconda. Don't try to install conda from pip (use Miniconda if that's all you want)

Comment: I don't want to install so many, I just want to use the one from the official website. but the anaconda installed python without my consent which I want to remove.@cricket_007

Comment: But you are doing `pip3 install conda` anyway... Miniconda is "offlcial" and doesn't install all the math packages from Anaconda https://conda.io/miniconda.html

Comment: @cricket_007 ok. but it is not question now. could you tell me how to fix my problem, delete all other pythons except the 3.7.0 which I installed by myself from the official website. and there is another problem here. only the python coming from the anaconda could the module and library from anaconda now, the others cannot! something wrong with my bash_profile?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but realistically, you should not be relying on installed packages across any more than one Python installation, regardless of where it was downloaded from. You should be using `conda` or `virtualenv` environments for each unique project that tracks your libraries for those

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not following you either. I am talking thing a. you are just talking thing b. that is not helpful. thank you anyway.

Comment: So, basically, Mac comes preinstalled with Python 2.7 and you should not attempt to change or alter that under any conditions. Downloading a newer version won't magically change that version. That does require a bashrc change. Most people use Homebrew to manage that for them, but I recommend `pyenv`  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: @cricket_007 still you are not talking my question here. I want to delete the one that anaconda brings with if you look at my question and the picture I uploaded. I am not talking about the preinstalled one.

Comment: Am I not? one of the question mark in your post is for "somehow, when I enter python in cmd, it turns out to be python 2.7??"

Comment: ok, thank you! sir. my question is how to delete the python module from the anacoda which is the python 3.6.5. as you can see, I cannot remove it on anaconda gui, or using conda remove xxx command. do you have any solutions?

Comment: You can't, as mentioned below. Anaconda is not a different Python, it's just a distribution of Python data science libraries plus the `conda` environment management tool. By uninstalling Python, none of those tools work, because they depend on Python. It's the same case for every version of Python, and you could have installed 3.6.5 and 3.7.0, but the package spaces would be different for each installation

Comment: thank u! sir!  I see! right now both the 3.7.0 version python (I installed) and the ipython cannot import any modules from the anaconda library, but the 3.6.5( installed by anaconda) can.  how am I supposed to fix it? let the 3.7.0 and ipython use the anaconda library like TensorFlow.

Comment: You need to use the corresponding conda or pip commands from the version that needs the libraries. Unfortunately, you'll need to do that every time you upgrade python, which is why it is a good practice to make a `requirements.txt` file that lists general versions and packages of external libraries for pip to install

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your comments correctly, what you are actually asking how to do is to:

- Install some packages using Anaconda
- Remove the Python version that was installed by Anaconda
- Keep using the Anaconda installed packages, but with the system Python

**You can't do this** - or if you can make it work somehow, you'll be causing yourself a lot of unnecessary trouble. Anaconda is designed to easily create self-consistent environments in which you can work with your choice of Python packages and to work independently of any other Python installations. You cannot use `conda` to remove Python from your base conda environment because conda itself depends on Python.

If you want to remove your complete installation of Anaconda, [follow their instructions](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/).

If you want to install additional Python packages to use with the Mac's system Python, [install and use `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17271319/24447).

Comment: I am using Mac. is there any chance I can delete the python which is with the anaconda while the previously  one pythonI installed by myself still could use the anaconda library and module. how am I supposed to delete the python which is with the anaconda. like the picture above I cannot delete it in GUI, also, I cannot remove it using conda remove command

Answer (score 0):

For the python downloaded form the official webpage you should be able to remove it from you applications on macOS. If you are on windows I found [this](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/installed.html) reference.

If you are trying to remove a version via anaconda use the `conda remove -n` command. More details [here](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-remove.html). To upgrade you can use `conda upgrade python` for the most recent version available. To see what is available you can do a `conda search`

Comment: thank u! sir. did you notice that I only want to keep the official python. and I am using Mac. and the conda remove does not work. it says ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.