# How to upgrade pandas on mac

Tags: python, pandas, upgrade

[image][image]I would like to upgrade my pandas from 0.19.2 to 0.121 on a Macbook.

I have tried with pip3 install --upgrade pandas and this does not work.

I also do not know what a bash shell is so please frame your answer as simply as possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by did not work? what is the full traceback if there is an error.

Comment: Can you cut and paste the error message into the question? Not an image please, but code text. It really helps to figure out the problem.

Comment: the error message was: bash: pip3: command not found

Comment: seems like you don't have pip installed on your system? First install pip and then the package you need? Maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x

Comment: i installed pip using that link and still pip3 install pandas did not work

Comment: @Leena it does not look like you tried `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Answer (score 1):

Was just having the same issue. You were close in your attempts, either had the commands out of order or had some other syntax errors. The following worked for me on my Mac:

```
pip3 install pandas --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by upgrading through Canopy>Package Manager>upgrade pandas. Thanks for the help.