# How do I fix this Python ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what is causing this file called builder.py to not run on mac even though it runs on windows. Code:

```
import cffi
import glob
import platform

# relative to build dir
LIB_BASE = '../libs/'
# compiling libraries statically to get a single binary
EXTRA_SRC = [LIB_BASE + 'subhook/subhook.c']

pltsysname = {'Windows': 'win32', 'Darwin': 'osx', 'Linux': 'elf'}
pltsrc = pltsysname[platform.system()]
pltsrc = LIB_BASE + 'plthook/plthook_{}.c'.format(pltsrc)
# EXTRA_SRC.append(pltsrc)  # disabled until it is actually useful

LIBDIRS = []
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
LIBDIRS.append('../libs/SDL/lib/x86/')

CDEFS = 'generated internals SDL XDL subhook xternPython'.split()


def readfile(name):
with open(name, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
return content


def build():
ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()

for fname in CDEFS:
    ffibuilder.cdef(readfile('cdefs/{}.h'.format(fname)))

ffibuilder.embedding_api('uint32_t kickstart();')
ffibuilder.embedding_init_code(readfile('remote.py'))

ffibuilder.set_source(
    '_remote', readfile('cdefs/remote.c'), sources=EXTRA_SRC,
    libraries=['SDL2'], library_dirs=LIBDIRS,
    define_macros=[('SUBHOOK_STATIC', None)])

ffibuilder.compile(tmpdir='build', target='remote.bin')


if __name__ == '__main__':
build()
```

When ever I run it I expect it to run but instead it comes up with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/alexanderlee/Desktop/sbpe-1.6.1/builder.py", line 1, in <module>
import cffi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cffi'
>>>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `pip install cffi`?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you only installed `cffi` on your Windows, so you probably need to install it on your Mac also.

You can follow rules on the [docs](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> `pip install cffi`

Comment: Sidenote: If you have 2 versions of Python, use pip2 or pip3 whatever whatever environment you're working on.

Comment: So where would I put this line of code? Or how do I install cffi?

Comment: @AlexLee In your command line, so for me it is command prompt.

Comment: @AlexLee Go to your toolbar of the desktop, and see tooltip of all, if one of them has command in it click on it.

Comment: @U9-Forward just one more thing, where do I access tooltip?

Comment: @AlexLee see: https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line

Comment: @U9-Forward I have done that but on the installation of cffi website it says install homebrew which I have done. I put in this command to install cffi: brew install pkg-config libffi
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig pip install cffi . But then the output is "bash - command pip not found" or something along those lines.

Comment: @U9-Forward no, please read the above comment, I do not know how to get the pip to work.

Comment: @AlexLee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x

Comment: @U9-Forward Pip has been installed, but there is some error preventing me from installing cffi.

Comment: @AlexLee Then, ya should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

`cffi` is a third-party module.  It's installed on your Windows computer but not on your Mac.

Comment: You're 14 second later than me... same answer.