# Installing python3-pip / flask on macOs Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, sudo, apt-get

I'm trying to install flask on my Mac and am struggling with the first step which is installing python3-pip. For reference, I'm using this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRwy8gtgJ1A&t=5m0s

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS does not have apt-get in the terminal.  Follow [this guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/) for directions on how to install pip on mac.  You can also reference [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947390/10101556)