# Install Modules Python 3.8.2 on mac

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I don't understand how to install packages in python. I just continually get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` regardless of the various commands I try. I have seen that I cannot write commands from the shell, but am not sure where else I would do this. help

```
>>> python3 pip install requests
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Run it on the system shell, not in the Python interpreter.

Comment: For python3 use `pip3 install requests`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `pip3 install requests` on your terminal/shell and not inside your python interpreter. The pip3 is used if the you are using version python 3.

Once the package is installed, you can use `import requests`to include it to your .py file.

Feel free to comment and ask for any further help with this. If you need help with installing pip itself, refer to this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x/)