# Both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on MacOS, but pip command install libraries only for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, module, python-requests

I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on my MacOS (Mojave 10.14.5). When I run my Python 2 code I get:

```
ImportError: No module named <modulename>
```

if I install the module with `pip install <modulename>` command i get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: <modulename> in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.5)
```

Then same missing package message as before when running the code with Python 2. The command `pip2 install <modulename>` is not working. How could I install modules for Python 2?

Comment: this seems to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043109/479251 (see "method 2 from 2019" in the linked answer).

Comment: This blog post can also be helpful, please try this, even if it's a bit old. https://blog.kinsacreative.com/articles/installing-python-2-and-python-3-alongside-each-ot/

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
python2 -m pip install <modulename>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get:
```-bash: python2: command not found```
(I am working on terminal)

Comment: How do you invoke python2 normally? e.g. if you normally just use "python" does "python -m pip install <modulename>" work? I don't have a MacOS computer to hand but I guess python2 might still be the default.

Comment: ```python --version``` gives ```Python 2.7.10```. To invoke python I simply use ```python <filename>.py```

Comment: In that case `python -m pip install <modulename>` should work if pip is installed.

Comment: with `python -m pip install <modulename>` I get `python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Ok, I managed to install the module with `python -m pip install --user the_module`. Now another problem, maybe worst: I need to install the package cvxpy which I think requires at least python 3.7 because It says ` RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.` Is there any possibility to get around this?

Comment: @Barbab that won't work, indeed it's worse. This installed the python3 version of your library