# Cant install pip on mac? Using VS code

Tags: python, terminal, pip

whenever i use the terminal and type pip3 install requests this is what happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 13, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 123, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "/Users/hawawague/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 63, in <module>
    from urllib.request import parse_http_list, getproxies, proxy_bypass, proxy_bypass_environment, getproxies_environment
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_http_list' from 'urllib.request' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py)
```

Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

then try again with `pip3 install requests`