# No module named urdf2webots - pip installed package outside of sys.path

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I installed a package via `pip install urdf2webots`. Upon using the command `python -m urdf2webots.importer --input=Rover_2022.urdf --output=Rover_2022.proto`, I get `/bin/python: No module named urdf2webots`. How do I fix this?

##### Without `sudo`

- `which python` returns `/bin/python`
- `pip show urdf2webots` returns

```
Name: urdf2webots
Version: 1.0.16
Summary: A converter between URDF and PROTO files.
Home-page: https://github.com/cyberbotics/urdf2webots
Author: Cyberbotics
Author-email: support@cyberbotics.com
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /home/drakeprovost/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: rospkg, pycollada, numpy, Pillow
Required-by:
```

- If I get `python` to print the sys.path, I get:

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>>>
```

##### With `sudo`

It's worth noting that I tried all these commands with `sudo` as well to see if it changed where the packages were installed. It did, but the problem persisted:

- `$ sudo python -m urdf2webots.importer --input=Rover_2022.urdf --output=Rover_2022.proto` yields `/usr/bin/python: No module named urdf2webots`
- `sudo which python` yields `/usr/bin/python`
- `sudo pip show urdf2webots` gives

```
Name: urdf2webots
Version: 1.0.16
Summary: A converter between URDF and PROTO files.
Home-page: https://github.com/cyberbotics/urdf2webots
Author: Cyberbotics
Author-email: support@cyberbotics.com
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
Requires: rospkg, Pillow, pycollada, numpy
Required-by:
```

- sys.path returns

```
$ sudo python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
>>>
```

---

I recognize that in both cases the location of `urdf2webots` does not match any of the paths from `sys.path`, but I don't know how to fix this. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
python -m pip install urdf2webots
```

This will install the library for the default python that you want to use.

Comment: After finally [finding a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043109/13055399) that made it so I'd stop getting `/bin/python: No module named pip` with this technique, this allowed me to install urdf2webots.