# Downgraded pip but can't upgrade it any more

Tags: python, pip

I downgraded my pip but I can't upgrade anymore

I am making a game in python, it would automatically pip install the packages needed. but sometimes, the users pip is not up to date, and it won't work(I am actually using Automator on mac) so in Automator I made it so it would pip install the latest pip version, to test it, I downgraded my pip version to  9.0.1 and now I can't upgrade my pip version anymore, it would just leave an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 54, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

I tried uninstalling pip but it just gave practically the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947390/7976758 `python -m ensurepip --default-pip --upgrade`

Comment: I tried `python -m ensurepip --default-pip --upgrade` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried almost everything but nothing is working

Comment: Tried to download `get-pip.py` and [install](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22get-pip.py%22) it?

Comment: I uninstalled python and installed again, and it is working now, Thanks