# Pip doesn't recognise python 3.5.1 as the latest version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-3.5

I have been struggling with module installations since i started with Python. i think the problem is that pip doesn't recognise python 3.5.1 as the latest version. I went to check my project interpreter (in pycharm 5) and it shows that I have python 3.5, 2.7 3.4 and 2.6 installed on my macbook pro. I also discovered that all the modules i've been struggling to install into python 3.5.1 are all installed in python 2.7. when I type

```
pip install pip
```

it shows me where the current version of pip is located, which is
in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
```

can someone please help me switch pip to python 3.5?

```
please!
```

Comment: I am working on a new Macbook Pro under the operating system OSX EL CAPITAN 10.11.2 (just thought you should know)

Comment: Do you have `pip3` installed i.e. could `pip3 install pip` do something?

Comment: now it says it's already installed into python 3.4, any idea how to... "update" pip3?

Comment: Go to the directory of the specific python installation, and run the pip executable found in there

Comment: Learn to use virtual environments - you will avoid many of these problems

Comment: This might be relevant, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797277/how-to-install-pip-in-a-new-python-installation

Answer (score 2):

Your default pip location (`pip`) is probably used for Python 2.7. For Python `3.5` you should have `pip3.5` available to install stuff.

```
pip3.5 install <pkg>
```

That should probably work, if it doesn't fall back to `pip3` which is bundled with python when installing if I recall correctly.

Comment: good idea, but it still won't work. all it does is                                                                                            "Collecting pygame
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from   versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command."