# Can't install pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

so I have Python 2.7.10 and I am trying to run a python script. However, I get `ImportError: No module named requests`. I tried `pip install requests`, but I got the error `-bash: pip: command not found` because I had removed pip because it was for python 3.5 earlier and I want it for 2.7.

However, for some reason I can't install pip. When I do `sudo easy_install pip`, I get the following:

`Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'usr/local/bin/pip'`

Is there another way for me to be able to install pip?

Comment: Try installing pip by this script: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797277/how-to-install-pip-in-a-new-python-installation

Comment: Also, you never need to manually remove pip (for the future). You can always prefix the pip you want with `python -m pip` (or use whatever Python interpreter you want), rather than just `pip`.

Comment: Removing system files is a complete disaster. Maybe your best way forward is to restore from backups and start over. Python with `virtualenv` is very easy to set up for multiple Python versions and library requirements; perhaps familiarize yourself with virtual environments.

Comment: Also, there are many situations where you cannot choose, but if you can, choosing Python 2 is the wrong choice now.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks so much for the replies. So I ran the get-pip.py script and got `pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. However, when I do `pip install requests` I still get `-bash: pip: command not found`. Really not sure what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately in this situation I think I had to use version 2 because of a certain API my group is trying to use